# Apply a function to each row, where the function uses all previous rows of the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, apply, aggregate-functions

I have a DataFrame that has a format similar to the following:

```
      date     customer_id    transaction_id    amount    fraud
2020-01-01               1                10        25        0
2020-01-01               2                11        14        1
2020-01-02               1                12        48        1
2020-01-02               2                13        12        1
2020-01-02               2                14        48        1
2020-01-03               1                15        30        0
```

It is sorted by `date`, `customer_id`, `transaction_id`.

I now want to create two new columns, `fraud_count` which will show the number of fraudulent (`fraud == 1`) transactions that this customer has made up to, but not including, the current date. `fraud_sum` will be the same, but the cumsum of the transaction amount, rather than the count.

```
      date     customer_id    transaction_id    amount    fraud    fraud_count    fraud_sum  
2020-01-01               1                10        25        0              0            0
2020-01-01               2                11        14        1              0            0
2020-01-02               1                12        48        1              0            0
2020-01-02               2                13        12        1              1           14
2020-01-02               2                14        41        1              1           14
2020-01-03               1                15        30        0              1           48
2020-01-03               2                16        88        0              3           67
```

How can I achieve this? Is it possible to create a function that looks at the entire DataFrame, or all rows before the current row, and then apply it to each row using `pd.DataFrame.apply()`?

Comment: filter out rows with date < today and then apply a groupby on `customer_id` and `aggregate` with function `cumsum` on columns `fraud` and `amount`.

Comment: Are your values correct? row 3 should have a amount of 25 not 0 according to your logic?

Comment: No because it should only count previous values where `fraud == 1`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need filter first only `1` values of `fraud` column, then aggregate counts and `sum` by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html), then create cumulative sum per `customer_id` and add next days for not matching previous ones:

```
df1 = df[df['fraud'].eq(1)].copy()
df1 = (df1.groupby(['customer_id', 'date'])
          .agg(fraud_count=('amount','size'),
               fraud_sum=('amount','sum'))
          .reset_index())
cols = ['fraud_sum','fraud_count']
df1[cols] = df1.groupby('customer_id')[cols].cumsum()
df1['date'] += pd.Timedelta(1, 'day')
```

And last use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with replace missing values:

```
df = df.merge(df1[['fraud_count','fraud_sum', 'date','customer_id']], 
              on=['date','customer_id'], how='left')

df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
        date  customer_id  transaction_id  amount  fraud  fraud_count  \
0 2020-01-01            1              10      25      0            0   
1 2020-01-01            2              11      14      1            0   
2 2020-01-02            1              12      48      1            0   
3 2020-01-02            2              13      12      1            1   
4 2020-01-02            2              14      41      1            1   
5 2020-01-03            1              15      30      0            1   
6 2020-01-03            2              16      88      0            3   

   fraud_sum  
0          0  
1          0  
2          0  
3         14  
4         14  
5         48  
6         67
```

Comment: Mine was similar to yours. But not complete yet. So, voted you up and removing mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    date4curr=df1.loc[ss.max(),'date']
    dd1=df1.loc[ss].loc[df1.date!=date4curr].query("fraud==1")
    df1.loc[ss.max(),'fraud_count']=dd1.fraud.sum()
    df1.loc[ss.max(),'fraud_sum']=dd1.amount.sum()
    return 1

df1.assign(col1=df1.index).groupby(['customer_id']).apply(lambda dd:dd.col1.expanding().apply(function1))
df1

：

      date     customer_id    transaction_id    amount    fraud    fraud_count    fraud_sum  
2020-01-01               1                10        25        0              0            0
2020-01-01               2                11        14        1              0            0
2020-01-02               1                12        48        1              0            0
2020-01-02               2                13        12        1              1           14
2020-01-02               2                14        41        1              1           14
2020-01-03               1                15        30        0              1           48
2020-01-03               2                16        88        0              3           67
```